# .Net datetime with milliseconds sql server using bulkcopy thows exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2005, sqlbulkcopy

I have this code, which throws exception.

```
SqlConnection con;
con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;     
cmd.CommandText = @"select [ID], [VERSION_ID], '08/26/2015 09:33:24:717 AM' as [Added_Dt],     [Loc_ID] as Column1
from dbo.Source where Added_Dt between CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/24/2015 09:25:43:283 AM') and CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/24/2015 09:25:43:283 AM')";

    cmd.CommandTimeout = con.ConnectionTimeout;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(destconnectionStr, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction);
    bcp.BatchSize = (int)Global.BatchWriteThreshold;
    bcp.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
    bcp.NotifyAfter = (int)Global.BatchWriteThreshold;
    bcp.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(bcp_SqlRowsCopied);
    bcp.WriteToServer(rdr);
```

> destination table(SQL Server 2005): ID (int, not null), VERSION_ID (int, not
>   null),Added_Dt(DATETIME,not null),Column1(varchar2(50) ,not null)

This throws exception if used with SqlBulkCopy but runs without any issues when using ado.net in single updates or directly from SQL Management Studio. I found that the removal of milliseconds part makes the bulkcopy run without exceptions but then I want the milliseconds to be there. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: What is the exact exception message?

Comment: Oh yes missed that!! {"The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'08/24/2015 09:25:43:283 AM'` is not a valid date string. The final `:` should be a `.`. Meaning:

`'08/24/2015 09:25:43.283 AM'`

Of course, this does convert without error in SSMS:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/24/2015 09:25:43:283 AM');
```

If fixing that doesn't help, then you need to provide the exact exception message.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks. that was too much small change to get ignored. Never knew that!!